# How to do bottom up recursion when the recursive function is async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, recursion

I have to recursively insert nested objects into mongodb.

Basically, the object I have has the following structure:

```
{
    'name' : 'Pepsi'
    'brands' : [
        {
            'name': 'Frito',
            'brands' : [
                {
                    'name' : 'Lays',
                },
                {
                    'name' : 'Cheetos'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'name' : 'Aquafina'
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, each object has brands, which can themselves have brands.

I want to insert the lowest level objects before higher level and then have a reference of that in it's parent. And in the final data I insert into mongodb, I just want one level of nesting. So, brands of Frito won't be visible in the mongodb document for 'Pepsi'

I wrote this recursive code:

```
function overEach(el, callback) {
    insertIntoDB(el);

    console.log('---');

    db.infom_col.insert(el, function(err, doc){
        if(err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log('abc' + id);

            delete doc[0].brands;
            callback(doc[0]);
        }
    });
}


function insertIntoDB(obj) {
    if(obj.brands) {
        var brands = obj.brands;

        async.map(obj.brands, overEach, function(err, results){
            obj.brands = results;
        });

    }
}
```

and then after `insertIntoDb()` is completed, I was inserting the main 'Pepsi' object. However, I think the function comes out of recursion before the db calls are complete.

So, **how do I insert the objects in a bottom up manner while maintaining a parent to child reference.**

Comment: How are you trying to maintain the parent child reference?

Comment: @WiredPrairie After I insert a child object, I store it's ID in the parent object. Basically, the `obj.brands = results` line is supposed to do that.

Comment: But, `doc[0]` isn't an `_id`, is it? It's likely that you won't want to just store the parent ID as MongoDB doesn't have graph-like capabilities for following relations: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Comment: yeah, doc[0] isn't an _id. it's the whole object. I was planning to  change it later on to store just the `_id`.

Comment: I think the problem is that when I call the function recursively, the function comes our of recursion before the mongodb insert command ends.

Comment: You might want to look at the `async` npm package and it's `series` or one of the other functions to process things in a more orderly fashion.